# How to write numbers (or a column of numbers ) as power of 10 in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf

I want to convert a column of numbers so as to write as number multiplied with powers of 10 along with some desired rounding off.
Here is an example of the column:

`cat file.dat`

```
-50449.9049902009
-223829.94550318
 2326760.18722836
 17525894.0307227
 33532898.4295385
 15980281.8371545
```

**I want to control the output format in a certain way either `x.xxxx * 10^y`, `x.xxxx * 10^z` etc.** i.e.

```
-5.0450*10^4
-2.23830*10^5
 2.326760*10^6
 1.7525894*10^7
 3.3532898*10^7
 1.5980282*10^7
```

or as **`x.xxxxx * 10^y`, `xx.xxxx * 10^y` etc.** i.e. as

```
-5.0450*10^4
-22.3830*10^4
 232.6760*10^4
 1752.5894*10^4
 3353.2898*10^4
 1598.0282*10^4
```

With `awk` and `sprintf`, I can only round off these numbers but not in the format above.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}{$1=sprintf("%1.0f",$1)}1' file.dat
-50450
-223830
 2326760
 17525894
 33532898
 15980282
```

Comment: Have a look at the format specifiers of `printf`. Have a look at `man 3 printf`. I believe you are interested in the format `%23.17e`. The following might work: `while read line; do printf "%25.17e\n" "$line"; done < file`

Comment: It is always better to use the exponential notation then something like `x.xxxx * 10^y`. Using the exponential notation, you can always easily reread the data in another file. Furthermore, it is better to print all digits needed to exactly recreate the binary representation of this number. This is for a double-precision number, 17 digits after the comma

Comment: @kvantour, Agree with you. Bust as you can see I am not worried about the precision loss of these numbers. Sometimes it needs to put in this format for presentation :)   You will get in `Mathematica` a several options for that.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this `awk`:

```
awk '{s = sprintf("%.7e", $1); sub(/e\+0*/, "*10^", s); print s}' file
```

```
-5.0449905*10^4
-2.2382995*10^5
2.3267602*10^6
1.7525894*10^7
3.3532898*10^7
1.5980282*10^7
```

---

As per dynamic precision control, you may try this `awk`:

```
awk '{n=int($1); if(n<0) n*=-1; m=length(n)}
     {s = sprintf("%." (m-1) "e", $1); sub(/e\+0*/, "*10^", s); print s}' file
```

```
-5.0450*10^4
-2.23830*10^5
2.326760*10^6
1.7525894*10^7
3.3532898*10^7
1.5980282*10^7
```

---

Sorry overlooked part 2 of your question. You may use this simple `awk`:

```
awk '{printf("%.4f*10^4\n", $1/10^4)}' file
```

```
-5.0450*10^4
-22.3830*10^4
232.6760*10^4
1752.5894*10^4
3353.2898*10^4
1598.0282*10^4
```

Comment: Great! But do you have any suggestion for the second scenario i.e writing instead as a fixed power of 10 and accordingly the decimal point shifts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python 3 to do this :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from decimal import Decimal

content="""-50449.9049902009
-223829.94550318
 2326760.18722836
 17525894.0307227
 33532898.4295385
 15980281.8371545"""

for line in content.split("\n"):
    print("{:.2E}".format(Decimal(line)))
```

Will output :

```
-5.04E+4
-2.24E+5
2.33E+6
1.75E+7
3.35E+7
1.60E+7
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question, you could use awk as well:

```
# awk -v y=4 '{printf("%f*10^%d\n", $1*10^-y,y)}' file.dat 
-5.044990*10^4
-22.382995*10^4
232.676019*10^4
1752.589403*10^4
3353.289843*10^4
1598.028184*10^4
```

Where the "y=4" is the exponent you'd like to use in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script with dc:

```
cat code.dc
[arguments]sT
[lTpq]sV
zd2>V1-sa
# nombre de valeurs
[Sbz1<A]sA
# macro empilement
sb
# premiere valeur dans b
2z>A
# empilement des valeurs dans b
[exposant negatif]sL
[lLpq]sW
dsc0>W
# format de sortie
[*10^]sd
# constante pour affichage
[leli+se]sZ
# macro pour ajuster la valeur
[
Lbse
# on stoque la valeur dans e
leZ sf
# nombre de chiffre total dans f
leX sg
# nombre de chiffre apres virgule dans g
lflg- sh
# nombre de chiffre avant virgule dans h
[_1si]sY
# macro pour signe de l arrondi si negatif
1sile0>Y
# control de l arrondi dans i
led1/- li * 0.5r!<Z
# ajustement de l arrondi
lh1- sj
# exposant dans j
[lcsj]sU
lc0!=U
10lj^ sk
# diviseur dans k
ljklelk/ n [*10^] n lj p
# affichage
c
# efface la pile
0k
# retablie la precision
la1-dsa0<B
# condition pour relancer la macro
]sB
lBx
```

and use it this way:

```
{ echo 0 ; cat file.dat | tr - _ ; cat code.dc ; } | dc
-5.0450*10^4
-2.23830*10^5
2.326760*10^6
1.7525894*10^7
3.3532898*10^7
1.5980282*10^7

{ echo 4 ; cat file.dat | tr - _ ; cat code.dc ; } | dc
-5.0450*10^4
-22.3830*10^4
232.6760*10^4
1752.5894*10^4
3353.2898*10^4
1598.0282*10^4
```

Sorry, but I don't try all the case.
You can't give a negative number with echo.
dc don't like negative number like -321.217, this why we use tr to convert to _321.217.